# Replace existing record with same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a drop down menu. It has consists of month, January until December. Basically, user may select any month before they enter other data. So, the problem now is **how to replace in database** (sql) if user choose May in the first login, then log out. The next time if he/she login and choose May again, the submit it, the new record of May will be replace the old record of May. 
Here is my example of my table in db,

|username|Month|Weight|Height|

The user will select month, enter weight and height, then click on submit button. The next page, it will display the record entered by user for that month. If yes, then save it in db and if no, return back to previous page. But i dont know how to check whether the user has selected the month or not. Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should try with following code,

```
IF(@month IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_name SET col1=@data1,col2=@data2,.....
        WHERE username=@username and month_col=@month;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--if @month is empty,do here some action
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET Month = @month WHERE username = @username
```

The `@month` is the month selected by the user and `@username` is the user name with which the user logged in.